# Why does test takes longer than specified implicitlyWait time to fail if the element is not present

Tags: selenium

For Example I have specified `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` in my code . So ideally if the element is not present it should fail the test after 50 seconds . But it takes around 2 minutes to fail the test with element not found exception . Can someone explain the concept of implicit wait clearly ?

Comment: Can you share your code for element not found exception ? Do you have explicit wait as well ? Are you mixing both of them ?

Comment: Actually i am using POM pattern and below is (part of code) of the test which i am testing  : portal.clickCustomSetup(true);
                    portal.clickCustomCorporation(true);
                  portal.clickClientPortalSettings(true); In all three methods implicit wait is mentioned(which i think is wrong ) . it should be mentioned in only one place of the test  . please clarify . When i remove all three implecit wait code ran faster and it threw exception in less time . 
           
           portal.checkReceiptDetailsCheckBox(true, 'c');

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you are using implicit wait in three methods and you think it's wrong, well the answer is - **yes it is wrong**.

See what selenium developers have mentioned :

**Implicit wait :**

An implicit wait is to tell **WebDriver** to poll the **DOM** for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is **0**. Once set, **the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance**.

So for a single execution, once you have written :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

you do not need to write it again . even if you do there will be no impact on webdriver.

Note that the implicit wait work at the web driver level.

I would suggest you to write **implicit wait** **code** under **fixtures or setup instance**.

In case if you are using **TestNG**, you can use `@BeforeMethod` annotation and can write the implicit wait there.

Let me know if you have anymore concerns.